# Problem solving a simple probability exercise

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution

**I'm currently studying a Statistics course and I'm trying to solve a simple probability exercise:**

A production facility employs:

- 20 workers on the day shift
- 15 workers on the swing shift
- 10 workers on the grave- yard shift

A quality control consultant is to select 6 of these workers for in-depth interviews. Suppose the selection is made in such a way that any particular group of 6 workers has the same chance of being selected as does any other group (drawing 6 slips without replacement from among 45).

The question is: *What is the probability that at least two different shifts will be represented among the selected workers?*

**My answer:**

I'm going to answer this question using two methods. I have a problem with the second method. Though, the first method is more recommended by instructors; when practicing I try to use both methods to make sure that my answer is correct and that I understand the material.

**Method 1:** Calculating ***the probability of 6 workers being selected from 45 workers***, then subtracting it with ***the probability of 6 workers being selected exactly from one different shift***.

P(A) = The probability of 6 workers being selected from 45 workers is obviously one: (45P6 / 45P6).

P(B) = The probability of 6 workers being selected from exactly one different shift is:
0.0054 (15P6 + 10P6 + 20P6 / 45P6)

P(Solution) = P(A) - P(B) = 1 - 0.0054 = 0.9946.

The solution 0.9946 is correct (verified from the answer key) and I have no problem with this method.

**Method 2:**  Calculating ***the probability of 6 workers being selected exactly from two different shifts*** and summing it with the ***the probability of 6 workers being selected exactly from three different shifts***.

P(C) = The probability of 6 workers being selected exactly from two different shifts: 0.29

(25P6 + 35P6 + 30P6 / 45P6). Note that 15+10=25 15+20=35, 20+10=30.

P(D) = The probability of 6 workers being selected exactly from three different shifts is: 1 (45P6/45P6).

Summing P(C) + P(D) will obviously give a wrong answer since the result will be above 1, which is clearly false.

What did I do wrong in method 2?

Comment: Assuming that nPm means the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{m}$, 25P6 is the number of subsets of size 6 that can be chosen from 10+15 = 25 people, but this includes subsets of size 6 chosen from just _one_ shift, does it not?

Comment: @DilipSarwate we use nPm for permutation and nCm for combination (also known as binomial coefficient (n m)).

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate **But this includes subsets of size 6 chosen from just one shift**. You're right. So, can I subtract  *subsets of size 6 chosen from just one shift* to get the correct probability or the method unanswerable using this method?

Comment: @DilipSarwate wait, I think I figured it out.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, 
P(C) = 25P6 + 35P6 + 30P6 - 2(15P6 + 10P6 + 20P6) / 45P6

Comment: @DilipSarwate, P(D) = (45P6 - (15P6 + 10P6 + 20P6) - (25P6 + 35P6 + 30P6)) / 45P6

Comment: P(Total) = (45P6 - 3(15P6 + 10P6 + 20P6)) / 45P6 = **0.9838** which is not exactly equal to the official answer **0.9946**. What is still missing?